# Do i have my file open statement written properly for this program to open a test.asm file of assembly instructions?

Tags: mips

I can't seem to figure this out. I have my fopen for test.asm but when i run the code, it just completes the run without having any interaction with instructions or creating an output file.

```
/*
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change this license
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/cFiles/main.c to edit this template
 */

/* 
 * File:   main.c
 * Author: Andrew Schelb
 *
 * Created on March 7, 2023, 2:51 PM
 */

#include<ctype.h>

#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


#define MAX_FILE_SIZE 1024 
unsigned char *MEMORY_STORAGE;

int main() {
    char filename[] = "test.asm";
    char buffer[MAX_FILE_SIZE];
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: could not open file %s\n", filename);
        exit(1);
    }
    size_t read_size = fread(buffer, 1, MAX_FILE_SIZE, fp);
    if (read_size == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: could not read from file %s\n", filename);
        exit(1);
    }
    // The file contents are now stored in buffer.
    // You can pass this buffer to the assembly code parser.
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

int allocateSpace(unsigned char *storage, int size)
{
    return(size);
}

int allocateWord(unsigned char *storage, int value)
{
    int offset = 0;
    offset = (storage - MEMORY_STORAGE) % 4;
    if (offset != 0)
    {
        offset = 4 - offset;
        storage += offset;
    }
    
        storage[0] = value >> 24;
        storage[1] = 0xFF & (value >> 16);
        storage[2] = 0xFF & (value >> 8);
        storage[3] = 0xFF & value;
    return(4 + offset);
}


unsigned char* trim(unsigned char *data)
{
    int i = 0;
    unsigned char *left = data;
    int len = strlen(data);
    while (isspace(*left) || *left == '$')
    {
        left++;
    }
    return(left);
}

unsigned int encodeRA(unsigned int function, unsigned char *param, unsigned int shamt )
{
    //0x00852020
    unsigned int result;
    unsigned char *tmp = malloc(sizeof(int)*1024);

    unsigned int rs,rt,rd;    
    strcpy(tmp, param);
    param = strtok(tmp, ",");
    rd = atoi(trim(param+1));
    param = strtok(NULL, ",");
    rs = atoi(trim(param+1));
    param = strtok(NULL, ",");
    rt = atoi(trim(param+1));




    result = rs << 21;
    result |= rt << 16;
    result |= rd << 11;
    result |= shamt << 6;
    result |= function;
    return(result);
}

unsigned int encodeRB(unsigned int function, unsigned char *param, unsigned int shamt )
{
    //0x00852020
    unsigned int result;
    unsigned char *tmp = malloc(sizeof(int)*1024);

    unsigned int rs,rt,rd;    
    rs = 0;
    strcpy(tmp, param);
    param = strtok(tmp, ",");
    rd = atoi(trim(param+1));
    param = strtok(NULL, ",");
    rt = atoi(trim(param+1));
    param = strtok(NULL, ",");
    shamt = atoi(trim(param+1));




    result = rs << 21;
    result |= rt << 16;
    result |= rd << 11;
    result |= shamt << 6;
    result |= function;
    return(result);
}


unsigned int encodeI(unsigned int opcode, char *param)
{
    
    unsigned char *tmp = malloc(sizeof(int)*1024);

    unsigned int rs,rt,immediate;    
    strcpy(tmp, param);
    param = strtok(tmp, ",");
    rs = atoi(trim(param+1));
    param = strtok(NULL, ",");
    rt = atoi(trim(param+1));
    param = strtok(NULL, ",");
    immediate = 0xFFFF & atoi(trim(param+1));    
    
    
    unsigned int result;
    result = immediate;
    result |= rt << 16;
    result |= rs << 21;
    result |= opcode << 26;
    return(result);
}




void printFILE(unsigned char *storage, char *outfile)
{
  
    FILE *file = fopen(outfile, "w");
    
    if (file == 0)
    {
        printf("Could not open output file\n");
        exit(2);
    }
    size_t data_out = fwrite(storage, 1, 1024, file); 
        
}

void printHEX(unsigned char *storage)
{
        for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
        {
                if (i == 512)
        {
            printf("\n\n");
        }

                if (i % 4 == 0)
                {
                        printf(" 0x" );
                }
                
                printf("%hhX", storage[i]);
                if (i % 16 == 15)
                {
                        printf("\n");
                }
        }
}


int divideOp(FILE *file)
{
        fprintf(file, "%d", 0x4634);
        fprintf(file, "%d", 0);
}



int encodeInstruction(unsigned char *line, unsigned char *data, unsigned char **storage )
{
    int offset = 0;
    char *instruction = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*1024);
    unsigned int curInstruction;
    strcpy(instruction,line);
    instruction = strcpy(instruction,line);
    instruction = strtok(instruction, "\t");
    char *param = strtok(NULL, "\t");
    
    if (strcmp(instruction, "add") == 0)
    {
        curInstruction = encodeRA(0x20, param, 0);
        offset = 4;
    }
    else if (strcmp(instruction, "sub") == 0)
    {
        curInstruction = encodeRA(0x22, param, 0);
        offset = 4;
    }
    else if (strcmp(instruction, "sll") == 0)
    {
        curInstruction = encodeRB(0x0, param, 0);
        offset = 4;
    }
    else if (strcmp(instruction, "blg") == 0)
    {
            curInstruction = encodeRA(0x2C, param, 0);
            offset = 0;
    }
    else if (strcmp(instruction, "srl") == 0)
    {
        curInstruction = encodeRB(0x02, param, 0);
        offset = 4;
    }
    else if (strcmp(instruction, "addi") == 0)
    {
        curInstruction = encodeI(0x8, param);
        offset = 4;
    }
    else if (strcmp(instruction, "slt") == 0)
    {
        curInstruction = encodeRA(0x2A, param, 0);
        offset = 4;
    }
    else if (strcmp(instruction, "wtf") == 0)
    {
            curInstruction = encodeRA(0x2B, param, 0);
            offset = 0;
    }
    else if (strcmp(instruction, ".word") == 0)
    {
        offset = 0;
        unsigned int value = atoi(trim(param));
        (*storage) += allocateWord(*storage, value);
        
    }
    else if (strcmp(instruction, ".space") == 0)
    {
        offset = 0;
        unsigned int value = atoi(trim(param));
        (*storage) += allocateSpace(*storage, value);
        
    }
    if (offset == 4)
    {
        data[0] = 0xFF & curInstruction >> 24;
        data[1] =  0xFF & curInstruction >> 16;
        data[2] =  0xFF & curInstruction >> 8;
        data[3] =  0xFF & curInstruction;
    }
    return(offset);
}


int main2(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char outfile[1024], infile[1024];
    infile[0] = 0;
    char requestText = 0, requestBinary = 0;
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("assemble {-o filename | -t} -i test.asm\n");
        return(1);
    }
    
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(argv[i], "-t") == 0)
        {
            requestText = 1;
        }
        else if(strcmp(argv[i], "-o") == 0)
        {
            i++;
            requestBinary = 1;
            strcpy(outfile, argv[i]);
        } 
        else if(strcmp(argv[i], "-i") == 0)
        {
            i++;
            strcpy(infile, argv[i]);
        }
        
    }
    
    if (requestBinary == 0 &&  requestText == 0)
    {
        printf("Must specify at least one output\n");
        return(0);
    }
    
    if (strlen(infile) == 0)
    {
        printf("Must specify input file with -i option\n");
        return(1);
    }
    
        int bytes = 0;
        unsigned char data[1024], *storage, *code, *curCode, *curStorage;
    storage = curStorage = MEMORY_STORAGE = data;
    code = curCode = data + 512;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
        {
            data[i] = 0;
        }
        
        unsigned char *line = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*1024);
        FILE *input = fopen(infile, "r");
    if (input == 0)
    {
        printf("Could not open input file\n");
        return(2);
    }
    while (fgets(line, 1024, input) != NULL)
    {
        curCode += encodeInstruction(line, curCode, &curStorage);
    }
    
    if (requestText)
    {
        printHEX(data);
    }
    if (requestBinary)
    {
        printFILE(data, outfile);
    }   
    return(0);
}
```

I tried running it, it just runs blank. It is supposed to take the instructions from the test.asm and write a binary output file as a result. Neither seem to be happening

Comment: This is written in C programming

Comment: The only part of this code that actually executes is `main()`.  That function does not call any of your other functions - so just how were you expecting anything to happen?

Comment: i was attempting to use main() to import the test.asm using command args store it into the buffer then pass along the buffer to the assembler in the main2().  it then takes the args for main() and runs them through parseAssembly to convert the assembly file into machine code then to binary and write an output.

Comment: I think it would be better to let your toolchain do that work for you at compile time rather than have your program do it at runtime. Unfortunately I don't really know how to do that.